# How to programatically set Terminal theme/profile

Tags: terminal, bash, automation

Context for this question: 
I'm writing a bash script to automatically setup any Mac with my tools/preferences, ideally with one command if possible.

The question:
I have a `.terminal` theme file that i use and i'd like for the script to be able to set it as the default terminal profile without having to do it through the GUI after running my script, is there a command for this?

Comment: I see i've been downvoted.. please leave a comment explaining if you think this is a bad question.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this but I hate it when people downvote with no explanation. IMO there ought to be a requirement to explain downvotes. This seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me. If someone thinks differently, I hope they'll explain why.

Comment: @TJLuoma Thank you. I know i'm new to this particular community so i'm open to criticism if this is a bad/misplaced question.

Comment: I use iTerm, not Terminal, so I can’t help, but I would check DuckDuckGo to see if there’s an AppleScript way to activate themes.

Comment: What tools and preferences and how often should t run. why isn't bsh startup files sufficient

Comment: @Mark I should clarify that the overall purpose of the script in setting tools and preferences was just provided for context for this question, the question itself is specifically about setting the terminal theme programmatically. If you are just curious about the script overall, here it is https://github.com/JemarJones/mac-os-config/blob/master/setup.sh. It's meant to only run once on a new Mac.

What i am looking for is a way to effectively do this https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/27888/312455 + set default within my bash script. Is there some way to do that with startup files?

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63062/where-are-the-terminal-settings-stored-on-os-x you need defaults write com.apple.terminal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright i've figured out a solution:

To set the terminal theme programmatically you need to write to your systems preferences. So the easiest way that i found to do this was to extract the user preferences from an existing mac first. This assumes that you've already imported your `.terminal` file into the profiles of the Terminal on your existing machine. So first on the existing mac you need to run the following **(My theme is called Material-Theme, replace that part with your own)**:

```
plutil -extract Window\ Settings.Material-Theme xml1 -o - ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist > theme.xml
```

This will create a `theme.xml` file for you to use in your script. The next thing is just to edit the file a little. This could be automated, but if you're like me you only need to do this part once, so i did this manually. Open the file and remove the surrounding xml at the top and bottom so that all you have is the dict, mine looked like this for reference: https://pastebin.com/zfXFRY2e.

Now in your script on the new machine you can just run the following to insert this theme into your user preferences:

```
theme=$(<theme.xml)
plutil -replace Window\ Settings.Material-Theme -xml "$theme" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
defaults write com.apple.Terminal "Default Window Settings" -string "Material-Theme"
defaults write com.apple.Terminal "Startup Window Settings" -string "Material-Theme"
```

Now after running the above when you fully close the Terminal app and restart it, your theme should be the default. This process can probably be improved but this worked for me!

Note you might also want to run `defaults read com.apple.Terminal` and check if there are any other keys that are relevant to your theme. In my case i found `"NSWindow Frame TTWindow Material-Theme" = "0 327 640 450 0 0 1280 777 ";` so my script includes this as well `defaults write com.apple.Terminal "NSWindow Frame TTWindow Material-Theme" -string "0 327 640 450 0 0 1280 777 "`